# Graph : detect cycle in a cycle

Tags: graph

You are given an undirected  graph .

It is known that graph will contain few cycles . Give some pointers to detect if we have a cycle which has a smaller cycle with in it .  If yes print out the bigger cycle nodes and smaller cycle nodes [image]

Here 1,2,9,8,6,5,1  has internalls  cycle of 5 3 4 6 5

```
Assume we have few functions already defined for us . You can leverage them to build over these . 
   class graph
{
    private:int n;
        int **a;
        int *reach;
        int *pos;
    public:graph(int k=10);
        void create();
        void dfs();
        void dfs(int v,int label);
        int begin(int v);
        int nextvert(int v);
};
```

Comment: is this a homework question?

Comment: No .. Asked in interview of amazon.com (india
0

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of cycles and hash of nodes with no of nodes

so cycle A ... contains 4 nodes and hashed Q,W,E,R
cycle B ... contains 5 nodes and hashed W,E,R,A,S

now search for cycles with common nodes ... if you find then you have some cycles with common edges